# Diferença entre monitor de Hoare vs Monitor Java

Tags: java, sistemas-distribuídos

Eu estou tentando entender uma coisa que ainda não consegui pegar direito o porque disso.

No meu livro de dsd, apresenta a seguinte afirmação

```
Nos monitores de Hoare, se uma thread (dentro do monitor) executa x.notify(), o monitor é cedido para uma das threads acordadas. Isto permite que a thread execute

if(!B) x.wait();

para aguardar pelo estabelecimento da condição B (quando a thread retomar a execução é certo que B permanece verdadeiro).
• Nos monitores Java, a thread que executa x.notify() permanece dentro do monitor; a thread acordada só prossegue quando a primeira dexar o monitor. Isto exige que o teste da condição B seja feito da seguinte forma:

while(!B) x.wait();

pois B pode ter mudado quando a thread acordada retomar a execução
```

Mesmo com essa explicação, ainda não consegui entender o porque nos monitores Java se usa While(!B) e nos monitores de Hoare se usa if(!B)